# Find and Remove some text in Excel Worksheet with c#

Tags: excel, cell

i wanna find some text for example "Joe" and remove it from where it is in Excel Worksheet with C# ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to use the Range.Replace method, and simply replace with an empty string.

```cs
static void ReplaceTextInExcelFile(string filename, string replace, string replacement)
{
    object m = Type.Missing;

    // open excel.
    Application app = new ApplicationClass();

    // open the workbook. 
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(
        filename,
        m, false, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m);

    // get the active worksheet. (Replace this if you need to.) 
    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

    // get the used range. 
    Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;

    // call the replace method to replace instances. 
    bool success = (bool)r.Replace(
        replace,
        replacement,
        XlLookAt.xlWhole,
        XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
        true, m, m, m);

    // save and close. 
    wb.Save();
    app.Quit();
    app = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for `Excel 2016`:

- Search for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` on your C:, copy it into your C# project, and include this as a reference.
- Assembly version should be `15.0.0.0`.

Code:

```
Excel.DisplayAlerts = false; // Prevent "Nothing found" dialogs.

var Excel = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;

foreach(Worksheet sheet in Excel.Sheets)
{
    bool success = sheet.Rows.Replace(What: "ABC",Replacement: "DEF");
}

Excel.DisplayAlerts = true;
```